# How to skip a blank cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to create a new worksheet and rename that sheet with hyperlink based on the value of cell in the "Master" sheet range("A5").

It will stop at a blank cell. What should I add to skip the blank cell and continue?

```
Function CheckSheetExists(ByVal name As String)
' checks if a worksheet already exists

Dim retVal As Boolean

retVal = False

For s = 1 To Sheets.Count
    If Sheets(s).name = name Then
        retVal = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next s

CheckSheetExists = retVal

End Function

Sub AutoAddSheet()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("Master").Range("A5")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange

    On Error Resume Next

    If CheckSheetExists(MyCell.Value) = False Then

        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

        With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            .name = MyCell.Value
            .Cells(3, 1) = MyCell.Value

        End With
    End If

On Error GoTo 0

MyCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=MyCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & MyCell.Value & "'!A1"

Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is likely this assignment:

```
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
```

The `End(xlDown)` method will stop on a blank cell (generally).

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) for more reliable ways to find the "last" cell in a given range.

You may also want to move your `MyCell.Hyperlinks.Add` statement *within* the `If CheckSheetExists` block, **and** you'll need to add logic to skip empty cells (if there are empty cells within the `MyRange`.

```
Sub AutoAddSheet()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

With Sheets("Master")
Set MyRange = .Range("A5")
Set MyRange = .Range(MyRange, .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each MyCell In MyRange

    On Error Resume Next

    If CheckSheetExists(MyCell.Value) = False And MyCell.Value <> vbNullString Then

        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

        With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            .name = MyCell.Value
            .Cells(3, 1) = MyCell.Value

        End With
        MyCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=MyCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & MyCell.Value & "'!A1"
    End If

On Error GoTo 0

Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Comment: This work perfectly, exactly what I need - Thanks David!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add check of blank cell in you loop, for example:
I added check in the second row (and end if just before end of loop) - it checks length of text in the cell:

```
For Each MyCell In MyRange
IF(LEN(MYCELL.VALUE)>0) THEN
    On Error Resume Next

    If CheckSheetExists(MyCell.Value) = False Then

        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

        With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            .name = MyCell.Value
            .Cells(3, 1) = MyCell.Value

        End With
    End If

On Error GoTo 0

MyCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=MyCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & MyCell.Value & "'!A1"
END IF
Next MyCell
```

EDIT:
I would change the function checking if WS exists:

```
Function CheckSheetExists(ByVal name As String) as boolean
dim WS as worksheet

on error resume next
set ws = Worksheet(name)
on error goto 0

if(ws is nothing) then
CheckSheetExists = false
else
CheckSheetExists = true
end if

set ws=nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
For Each MyCell In MyRange
    If MyCell.Value <> "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
            If CheckSheetExists(MyCell.Value) = False Then
                Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                    .Name = MyCell.Value
                    .Cells(3, 1) = MyCell.Value
                End With
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        MyCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=MyCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & MyCell.Value & "'!A1"
    End If
Next MyCell
```